# Change Font Of Embed/Object Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `hotline.txt` file, and I want the content to be display in the webpage, the problem is I don't know how to change the font of the hotline.txt content. I use html  to display the content of `hotline.txt`.

Here is my code:

```
<object class="contact-num" data="S:\IT\Public\Reporting\Intranet\Hotline\Hotline Guide.txt"></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to change the style. If you want it to be on the same line, you can do:

```
<object class="contact-num" data="S:\IT\Public\Reporting\Intranet\Hotline\Hotline Guide.txt" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS"></object>
```

Or, for better code reading, you can put it on the `style` mark on `head` or link an external CSS stylesheet.

```
/*====================
---On <head></head>---
======================*/
<style>
.contact-num{
    font-family: Arial;
}
</style>
/*==========================================================================================
---On the archive corresponding to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url.css">---
============================================================================================*/
.contact-num{
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: Actually i already use css but the font wont change, did you have any other method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't style elements outside of the current document boundaries.

You can however load the .txt file with `ajax` to add it to the document and style it.
Below an example of `ajax` usage using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "pathToYourFile",
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        var resourceContent = data; // can be a global variable too...
        // process the content...
    }
  });
});
```

Further documentation on ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/